# JavaScript: Multiple Document.Write

Tags: javascript

I have a quiz and it is functioning properly.  However, the Incorrect Questions will not show when the Correct Questions portion is there.  (Works when the Correct Question portion isn't there)

Correct Question Portion of Script:

```
var cmessage = '<p>You got ' + score;
cmessage += ' out of ' + questions.length;
cmessage += ' questions correct.<br>' + '<p>' + '<p> Correct Answers: ' + '<br>';

for(var c in cA) {
  cmessage += questions[cA[c]][0] + '<br>' + questions[cA[c]][1] + '<br>';
}

document.write('<br>' + cmessage + '</br>');
```

Incorrect question portion:

```
var imessage  = '<br><br><p>You answered ' + incorrect.length;
imessage  += '<p> questions incorrect. Your incorrect questions: </p>';

for(var i in incorrect){
  imessage  += '<p> ' + questions[incorrect[i]][0] + '<br>' + questions[incorrect[i]][1] + ' </p>';
}

document.write('<p>' + imessage  + '</p>');
```

How do I get the Incorrect portion to show up on the page as well?

Comment: Who is teaching you to use `document.write()`? Very bad form. Get your money back.

Comment: What would be a better method?  All for learning a new one.

Comment: `document.write` just replaces the entire document contents every time you invoke it. You can manipulate individual DOM nodes with many different JavaScript methods. There are also great tools, like jQuery, to handle this for you, and awesome frameworks, like React, so that you don't even have to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: The better approach is to locate a pre-existing element in the DOM and modify its contents, rather than having to write your JavaScript inline and hope you don't overwrite the whole document by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to add the result to a div in the DOM.

```js
var imessage = '<b>foo</b>';
var cmessage = '<b>bar</b>'

var divCorrect = document.getElementById('correct');
var divIncorrect = document.getElementById('incorrect');

divCorrect.innerHTML = cmessage;
divIncorrect.innerHTML = imessage;
```

```html
<div id="correct"></div>
<div id="incorrect"></div>
```

---

In response to the comment that this answer is not relevant:

I proposed this solution because the OP's problem stems from the use of document.write, which overwrites everything in the DOM.  The second use of document.write will overwrite what was added with the first use.  Thus, the appropriate approach is to modify elements in the DOM.  This can be done with innerHTML.  Using innerHTML instead of document.write will prevent the second modification from overwriting the first (assuming the two modifications target different DOM elements, which is what my example demonstrates).

Comment: Irrelevant answer however question describes something else.

Comment: @AsadAli : how is this irrelevant?  The question asks why document.write isn't working.  One solution is to use innerHTML in order to prevent the entire DOM overwrite with document.write.  This allows multiple changes to the DOM without overwriting the entire document, which is the cause of the OP's problem.  The solution IS to not use document.write and to instead modify specific DOM elements.